# Catalog Advance Search in left sidebar 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, category-products

Added **advance catalog search** on **left side bar** in category page but breadcrumb not show correctly. So how to remove catalog advance search breadcrumb from category view page.
my code is as below

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalogsearch/advanced_form" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" template="catalogsearch/advanced/left_form.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your question you want to `remove catalog advance search`.

`app\design\frontend\coolbaby\default\layout\catalog.xml`

find `<catalog_category_layered>`

and commend eg:

```
<!--<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalogsearch/advanced_form" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" template="catalogsearch/advanced/left_form.phtml"/>
 </reference>-->
```

After this clear(delete folders) cache in `var/cache` folder.

I hope you it will work.

Comment: plz read properly, i dont want to remove catalog advance search but my problem is after adding catalog advance search in left side category page breadcrumb also set catalog advance search crumb. so how to set proper breacrumb in cateory page

Comment: @NikunjPatel: You mean alignment issues?

Comment: no there extra crumb(catalog advance search) show in breadcrumb